# My laptop back cover is not properly fitting in front side

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure

I accidentally spilled water on my laptop. I immediately switched off the laptop and disassembled it by removing the ram, hard drive, battery. For 48hrs I didn't touch my laptop and occasionally switched on ceiling fan to dry the interiors.

Now, when i try to put the laptops back cover in place. I see a gap that isn't closing.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what we could say except take it apart again & check you didn't trap or misalign something. Also test the battery isn't swollen.

BTW, if you just took it all apart & let it dry naturally, then you only did half a job. You should have immediately washed it down in isopropyl or contact cleaner to dissipate the moisture, preventing corrosion. Shorting is only the immediate danger. The more insidious is corrosion.

Comment: I don't have contact cleaner with me also i don't think i am capable of using it. should i take it to a repair shop? The laptop is working fine though!
I think the battery might be swollen but, I cannot figure it out from outside. Is there any way I can fix the battery?

Comment: You're far too late for contact cleaner. The damage has already been done. Batteries are unfixable. Best recourse would be let a repair shop see what else got damaged.